# check_mk for raspberrypi Vmalloc address space faulty warning

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have two raspberry pi which I've added to check_mk. Both of them get the following cirical error:

**"Vmalloc address space, CRIT - total 1088.0 MB, used 0.0 MB, largest   chunk 0.0 MB (critical at 32.0 MB!!)"**

I'm guessing this has something to do with the check_mk_agent that is running on raspberry pi is not working properly?

Version of omd which I have installed: omd-1.30_0.jessie_armhf
Agent version: check-mk-agent_1.2.6p12-1_all

Does anyone know how to avoid these critical warning without disabling them permanently?